# Reading querystring's in C# or JS?

Tags: javascript, c#

Appologies if this post is incorrectly tagged, i'm not sure if this would be a JS or C# implementation.

I have a pre-built shopping cart solution that has a list & details page. When a user clicks an item in the list it takes them to the details and passes a querystring value for product ID which loads the item.

I'm trying to read this querystring and pull just 1 piece of information from it but not sure how to do so.

```
http://example.com/Product/rvdsfpid/w521q-hf-cleo-20/rvdsfcatid/bedroom-5
```

The data i need is inside the `rvdsfpid` portion and i want to grab ONLY the information after the last hyphen `-` in this particular example it's `20` as that is my product id.

the urls do change in # of hyphens depending on the product ID that is the begging part and should there be spaces in that name it would represent additional hyphens in this value so how could I grab only whats after the last hyphen regardless how many there are in there from only the `rvdsfpid` string.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Are you building an ASP.NET WebForms or MVC application by chance? Generally you never have to manually parse a query string; the parts of the URL get bound to parameters in your controller actions, and are readily available to you.

Comment: I'm not sure where to start actually. I need the ID because i'm creating a custom token that needs that value i'm just not sure how to grab it.

Comment: @Cory i'm using the DNN CMS and have a shopping cart module with my products, but i'm trying to build a custom view of the data inside that modules tables that is "Printer Friendly" and for this i'm trying to create a script that grabs my info from the DB and loads it via a token. problem is I need a product ID to pass into my TSQL and i cannot read that full querystring value as it will return an error in my TSQL if its not only product ID.

Comment: If you were to separate the query string at every `/`, wouldn't the ID you want be in the field following the one that reads `rvdsfpid`?

Comment: @blaze_125 no the `rvdsfpid` contains two pieces of information the product sku + product ID. so in this case the sku = `w521q hf cleo` & the ID = `20` and i do not know how to separate them.

Comment: Then your sample seems inaccurate. In this `/rvdsfpid/w521q-hf-cleo-20/`, if you were to split at every `/`, the ID `20` actually sits in array[1], not array[0] as you seem to imply.

Comment: The string after `rvdsfpid` is the combination of those two infos Sku + ID at then end of the string. I'm not sure I understand your comment. My goal here is to read that string and grab only the ID portion which is the latter part of the string.

Comment: So really you want to pull the last number in the string following directly after `rvdsfpid`? If that is correct, my snippet below could help you in C#, and porting it to JavaScript should be trivial.

Comment: @blaze_125 i've added a screenshot which might make it more clear.

Comment: After seeing your screenshot, my below snippet does what you want in C#. Let me see if I can respin it in Javascript.

Comment: That would be very helpful! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the ID you want is indeed in the url part following the url part that reads `rvdsfpid`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string theProdId = GetProdIDFromQstring("rvdsfpid");
}

public static string GetProdIDFromQstring(string lookFor)
{
    string retval = string.Empty;
    string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;//get the url
    List<string> urlParts = url.Split('/').ToList();//split the url parts

    int fieldPosition = urlParts.FindIndex(p => p == lookFor);//find where your target is

    if (fieldPosition > -1)//if the field exists
    {
    retval = urlParts[fieldPosition + 1].Split('-').Last();//get the last part of this splitted string
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Here it is in Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log(GetProdIdFromQstring("rvdsfpid"));

function GetProdIdFromQstring(myTarget) {
    var url = location.href;//grab the url
    var splitted = url.split("/");//split it into parts
    var position = splitted.indexOf(myTarget);//find your target position
    if (position > -1) {
        //if we found your target
        var resplit = splitted[position + 1].split("-");//split this string
        return resplit[resplit.length - 1];//return only the last part(which should be the id)
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: My pleasure! Anytime!